# getwhere() error in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-2

How i call solve the error?

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::getwhere() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_learn\application\models\employee_model.php on line 18



<?php 
class Employee_model extends CI_Model {
function Employee_model()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function employee_getall()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('employee');
    return $query->result();
}

function employee_get()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->getwhere('employee', array('id' => 1));
    return $query->row_array();
}
} ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), `getwhere()` was changed to `get_where()`.  Looking back at the [CodeIgniter Git log](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/88f8d9f4c9d590cc14e71cd77f34e5e2abe57e21), it looks like it was removed on August 6, 2010 so any releases after that don't have it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
class Employee_model extends CI_Model {
function Employee_model()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function employee_getall()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('employee');
    return $query->result();
}

function employee_get()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('employee', array('id' => 1));
    return $query->row_array();
}
} ?>
```

Looking back at the [CodeIgniter Gitlog][1], it looks like it was removed on August 6, 2010 so any releases after that don't have it.According to the **docs**, `getwhere()` was changed to `get_where()`.